# Spring data Negative value passed to setFirstResult

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I have a simple PagingAndSortingRepository with Spring data and a query like this:

```
public List<VhSequenceEntity> findByCampaignIdAndOrganizationId(
        @Param("campaignId") Long campaignId, @Param("organizationId") Long organizationId, Pageable pageable);
```

When I use it with a single page query it gets the information correctly but when the paging information changes I'm having the following error:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Negative value (-727379968) passed to setFirstResult; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Negative value (-727379968) passed to setFirstResult
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:384)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:246)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:491)
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy107.findByCampaignIdAndOrganizationId(Unknown Source)
```

I googled this error but the results are not related to the process I'm executing.

Thanks!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When changing the paging information I was setting a value too big for the page parameter. So if you get this error please be sure you are setting the correct values to each parameter in the pageable object.